# How do I refresh the page when I update the loaded Resource dictionaries in Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, resourcedictionary

I am trying to define two themes in my Windows Phone 7.5 app. I have done this using two ResourceDictionaries (one for 'light' and another for 'dark') which are included as Content and then loaded using something like,

```
PresentationFrameworkCollection<ResourceDictionary> currResourceDictionaries 
    = Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries;
currResourceDictionaries.Clear();
ResourceDictionary d = new ResourceDictionary() 
{ 
    Source = new Uri("/View/LightResourceDictionary.xaml", UriKind.Relative) 
};
currResourceDictionaries.Add(d);
```

This works fine for any newly created pages, but for already instatiated page (e.g. the Settings page where the themes are set) then the bound StaticResources are not updated.

How can I get the bound resources to update for currently loaded pages?

Comment: are you removing the existing custom themes/resources before adding the new one?

Comment: I `Clear()` the `currResourceDictionaries` object in the 2nd (3rd?) line as far as I can tell ...

Comment: apologies, I didn't see that. I was going to suggest trying [WP ThemeManager](https://github.com/jeffwilcox/wp-thememanager/blob/master/src/JeffWilcox.PhoneThemeManager/ThemeManager.cs), the source code probably has the answer.